# Why web.xml does not work when I do not use a global namespace?

Tags: xml, tomcat, jakarta-ee, namespaces, web.xml

I have this very simple web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>testx.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I deploy the application and visit the context root, I will be taken to testx.jsp which is fine. But in my web.xml file I do not want to use a global namespace so I change the web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ee:web-app xmlns:ee="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
            version="3.1">
    <ee:welcome-file-list>
        <ee:welcome-file>testx.jsp</ee:welcome-file>
    </ee:welcome-file-list>    
</ee:web-app>
```

Now when I again start tomcat and visit the page, I will find myself in /index instead of /testx.jsp. But why?

I am deploying the application to Tomcat Server. I tried Glassfish and I did not encounter this problem. I guess this is a Tomcat problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is correct and valid, but the `xmlNamespaceAware` property of your Tomcat web application Context is probably set to false (default).

I was able to reproduce the behavior you describe with a web.xml that uses namespace-prefixes for the elements, like your example. After modifying the `%CATALINA_HOME%/conf/context.xml` to add the xmlNamespaceAware attribute set to true `<Context xmlNamespaceAware="true">`, the welcome-file-list behaved as expected.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

> **xmlNamespaceAware**
>
> If the value of this flag is true, the parsing of web.xml and
> web-fragment.xml files for this web application will be
> namespace-aware. Note that *.tld, *.jspx and *.tagx files are always
> parsed using a namespace-aware parser and that the tagPlugins.xml file
> (if any) is never parsed using a namespace-aware parser. Note also
> that if you turn this flag on, you should probably also turn
> xmlValidation on. If the org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE
> system property is set to true, the default value of this attribute
> will be true, else the default value will be false. Setting this
> attribute to true will incur a performance penalty.

Comment: Why would this be off by default?